# remove country labels in deck.gl html export

Tags: python, data-visualization, mapbox, deck.gl, kepler.gl

We are using **deck.gl** to visualize our data. It looks great, however, in the plot basemap, there are still the country names as labels.

In the API **kepler.gl** there is an option to hide the labels. We are looking for the same functionality in deck.gl

**Does anyone know how to remove those from the basemap? Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CARTO basemaps with no labels, check docs [here](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/carto/basemap#supported-basemaps)!